# How to add query returned value to selection field in odoo 15

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15

i want to add this returned list from get_famille_list function to selection field in odoo-15

**get_famille_list function :**

```
def get_famille_list(self):
    all_fam = []
    query = """ SELECT x FROM product_template WHERE x !='' """
    self.env.cr.execute(query)
    data = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    for fam in data:
        all_fam.append(fam[0])
    return all_fam
```

And this is how i link the selection with the returned list from get_famille_list function

```
famille = fields.Selection(selection='get_famille_list')
```

expected data (selection= x1,x2,x3)

insteed of showing the correct data in the selection field it shows something weird, see the image

[image]

i can't figure out why it shows this.
any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a list of pairs [(value, label)](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Selection).

You just need to append a tuple to the `all_fam` list

***Example:***

```
def get_famille_list(self):
    all_fam = []
    query = """ SELECT x FROM product_template WHERE x !='' """
    self.env.cr.execute(query)
    data = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    for fam in data:
        all_fam.append((fam[0], fam[0].capitalize()))
    return all_fam
```

Comment: i tried your code but it game me this error 
TypeError: list.append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: i added [] to the args and it works

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the closing parenthesis

Comment: no problem you helped me